# 1 way 2 stack and 2 way 2 stack Pushdown Accepters that accepts $L=\{a^{(n^2)} \mid n \geq 1\}$

Tags: automata, finite-automata, pushdown-automata, stacks

Using a 1 way 2 stack, and a 2 way 2 stack PDA, I want to check if the length of an input string is strictly a perfect square number. How can I do this in both approaches?

Comment: Hint: $1+3+5+\dots+(2i-1) = i^2$.